# MySQL выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

подскажите, как с помощью SQL запроса получить два поля из разных таблиц.

Нужно: 
Получить поле id из таблицы store_package_purchases и соответствующие значения name из таблицы store_packages. Связаны они так: поле package из таблицы store_package_purchases = полю id из таблицы store_packages.

Я пытался делать, как-то так:

```
(SELECT id, package AS p_id
 FROM store_package_purchases
 ORDER BY purchase_timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 10)
UNION 
(SELECT name
 FROM store_packages
 WHERE id = p_id)
```

Что делаю не так и как изменить запрос таким образом, чтобы он отвечал моим требованиям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT spp.id, spp.package, sp.name
FROM store_package_purchases spp 
  INNER JOIN `store_packages` sp ON sp.id = spp.package
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, b.name
FROM store_package_purchases AS a LEFT JOIN store_packages AS b ON (a.package=b.id)
ORDER BY a.purchase_timestamp DESC LIMIT 10
```

[MySQL LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

> Если нет соответствующей строки для правой таблицы в части ON или USING в LEFT JOIN, для правой таблицы используется строка со всеми столбцами, установленными в NULL.